# TypeORM: auto generated UUID in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, typescript, uuid, typeorm

I am writing a REST API and for data access I am using TypeORM. I have used this successfully but I would like to have a UUID auto-generated primary key on one of my tables.

Does anyone know how to set up a column in TypeORM that is a UUID type and auto-generated? I have tried the following:

Using `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()`

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: string;
```

This gives me an exception when synchronising with the database:

```
TypeORM connection error: Error: column "id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
app.ts:65
at new QueryFailedError (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:27:28)
at Query.callback (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:216:38)
at Query.handleError (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:143:17)
at Connection.connectedErrorHandler (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:26)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:210:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:118:12)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
```

Using `@PrimaryColumn` and `@Generated`

```
@PrimaryColumn({type:"uuid"})
@Generated("uuid") id: string;
```

I get the following error when attempting this:

```
TypeORM connection error: Error: sequence "SystemUser_id_seq" does not exist
app.ts:65
at new QueryFailedError (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:27:28)
at Query.callback (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:216:38)
at Query.handleError (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:143:17)
at Connection.connectedErrorHandler (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:26)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:210:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/neilstevens/repositories/Capp.co/capp/ms/ms-token-server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:118:12)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
```

So it looks like this way I can get a primary column but TypeORM is not creating the sequence required for this to be an auto-generated column.

If I use `@PrimaryColumn({type: "uuid"})` then I do get a UUID column in the table but **NOT** an auto-generated column.

I cannot see any other way to achieve this so could someone please advise if this is a) even possible and b) how one would go about creating a auto-generated UUID column...please?

Answer (score 116):

Try:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
id: string;
```

Also, if you don't need a primary column, but need to generate uuid sequence, you can try this:

```
@Column()
@Generated("uuid")
uuid: string;
```

Comment: typeorm also have "increment", "rowid", and "identity" as a parameter for the decorator. does anyone know their use-cases? I know the "increment" one but what about the others?

Comment: @aryankarim, described in docs https://typeorm.io/decorator-reference#primarygeneratedcolumn

Answer (score 29):

As of Typeorm version `0.1.16`, the decorator `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` supports `uuid` for all databases.

**Usage:**

```
@Entity()
class MyClass {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

}
```

If your version of Postgres doesn't already include `uuid-ossp` (used to generate the UUID), you can install it using `create extension "uuid-ossp";`.

Answer (score 10):

for me, I use this shape

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string
```

we can use another shape
you should install the `UUID` package

`@PrimaryColumn() id:string`
and used the  `@BeforeInsert() genarate(){ this.id=uuid()`

Answer (score 8):

In the migration you could try setting the default value with uuid_generate_v4() this:

```
enter columns: [
        {
          name: 'id',
          type: 'varchar',
          isPrimary: true,
          generationStrategy: 'uuid',
          default: 'uuid_generate_v4()',
        },
```

In the Model component I set the id as below:

```
@Entity('<table_name>') 
class SvcRequest {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

After effecting the changes others have talked about. Specifically in my case:

```
 @Column({ primary: true, generated: 'uuid' })
  id: string;
```

I also had to let TypeOrm Synchronize the changes to my database table. I had set synchronize to false in OrmConfig.json and that's why the changes were not taking effect. So also enable TypeOrm to effect the changes by setting :

```
  "synchronize": true
```

in your orm configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I am using for Postgres 9.6 and 10. UUID is generated by default.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  uuid UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
);
```

However, I haven't been using the UUID as my primary key. This is here mainly for migration purposes. What I do know is that its unique, and haven't had a collision yet in the development environment. You can try replacing NOT NULL and UNIQUE with PRIMARY KEY instead.